# Python Text Loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

What I’m trying to do is when it gets to else and prints error I want it to loop back to choice1.

```
choice1 = input("Were would " + name + " like to go?\nThe Kitchen\nThe Couch\nOutside")
if choice1 == "The Kitchen":
  choices.append("The Kitchen")
  print(name + " walked towards The Kitchen.")
elif choice1 == "The Couch":
  choices.append("The Couch")
  print(name + " went and had sat on The Couch.")
elif choice1 == "Outside":
  choices.append("Outside")
  print(name + " put on their pack and went out the door.")
else:
  print("error")
```

If there’s an error/it reaches else I want it to loop back to choice1.

Comment: From friends trying to help me I never understood/done anything with loops. We tried whiles and things like that but we couldn’t figure it out.

Comment: Almost all the answers are not pythonics, this shows that Python is becoming famous... makes me sad...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try my best to answer the pythonic way (even though I dont consider myself Python expert): Python is so great with lists and dictionnaries that you can avoid things like switch/case stuff. Here's your comparison the Python way:

```
name = "Olivier"
possible_choices = {
   "The Kitchen": lambda name: "{} walked towards The Kitchen.".format(name),
   "The Couch": lambda name: "{} went and had sat on The Couch.".format(name),
   "Outside": lambda name: "{} put on their pack and went out the door.".format(name),
}
while True:
    choice = input("Were would {} like to go?\n{}\n>".format(
        name, '\n'.join(possible_choices)))
    if choice in possible_choices:
        print(possible_choices[choice](name))
        break;  # break the loop
    print("error")  # loops
```

With that:

- you have no "switch/case" because Python makes it possible,
- if you just add a key + lambda everything will work
- it's shorter thus:

  - it's easier to read
  - it's easier to maintain
  - it's easier to understand
  - thus it'll cost *less* to your company in the long run

Learn how to use lambdas (= anonymous functions) which are used in every modern language, and this "`if choice in possible_choices`" is so clear that it makes it almost English!

Comment: This had really helped me out and thanks to it my stuff is working properly now. I thank you for helping me with my problem!

Comment: I don’t know how exactly and I need 15 rep for my rep to other people to be public.

Comment: There's a checkbox just under the up and down arrows of my answer, if you click on it this means "ok this answer solved it"  **`;)`**

Answer (score -1):

```
while True:
    choice1 = raw_input("Were would " + name + " like to go?\nThe Kitchen\nThe Couch\nOutside")
    if choice1 == "The Kitchen":
      choices.append("The Kitchen")      
      print(name + " walked towards The Kitchen.")
      break
    elif choice1 == "The Couch":
      choices.append("The Couch")
      print(name + " went and had sat on The Couch.")
      break
    elif choice1 == "Outside":
      choices.append("Outside")
      print(name + " put on their pack and went out the door.")
      break
    else:
      print("error")
      continue
```

Comment: in the if statement, break has to be after the print statement

Comment: A `continue` at the end of the loop does not make any sense.

Answer (score -1):

You could use a while loop and have the if/elif statements make it escape the loop. Like this:

```
a = True
while a:
    choice1 = input("Were would " + name + " like to go?\nThe Kitchen\nThe Couch\nOutside")            
    if choice1 == "The Kitchen":
        choices.append("The Kitchen")
        print(name + " walked towards The Kitchen.")
        a = False
    elif choice1 == "The Couch":
        choices.append("The Couch")
        print(name + " went and had sat on The Couch.")
        a = False
    elif choice1 == "Outside":
        choices.append("Outside")
        print(name + " put on their pack and went out the door.")
        a = False
    else:
        print("error")
```

a is a boolean statement set to true. The script enters a while loop that runs while a == True. All of the if/elif statements make a false, causing the loop to end.